# threshold is a matrix full of zeros. why?

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing

I am trying to write a program where there's an image as input and I display the image according to  game of life rules. But the threshold is all zeros. I am not sure why since my binary image has both white and black pixels.

Code:

```
SOL = cv2.imread(r'path')

grayscale = cv2.cvtColor(SOL, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

threshold = cv2.threshold(grayscale, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY +cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

threshold = np.where((threshold!=0)& (threshold !=255),255, threshold)

....

def gameOfLife_rules(threshold):

    matrix = threshold // 255
    # same as in the same size and wrap
    neighbors_count = convolve2d(matrix, np.ones((3, 3)), mode='same', boundary='wrap') - matrix

    birth = (neighbors_count == 3) & (matrix == 0)
    survival = ((neighbors_count == 2) | (neighbors_count == 3)) & (matrix == 1)

    updated_matrix = np.zeros_like(matrix)
    updated_matrix[birth | survival] = 1

    return updated_matrix
```

Is threshold making this not work? The picture I get from this method is blank. All white pixels are gone.

Comment: What is the `np.where` line supposed to do? Otsu threshold might or might not work correctly on your image, depending on what it’s like. Could you share an example?

Comment: Is your array `int` dtype?

Comment: If `threshold` has int values between 0 and 255, what will `matrix` (`.//255`) be?

Comment: the first integer value that you pass (in your case `0`) is the threshold (see [the docs](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d7/d1b/group__imgproc__misc.html#gae8a4a146d1ca78c626a53577199e9c57)). So all values above 0 (so all values) are mapped to `255` (blank). Try to use an appropriate value as threhsold (see [this tutorial](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d7/d4d/tutorial_py_thresholding.html) for examples)

Comment: @CrisLuengo I am using Euclid's hexagon construction image(black & white). When I do cv2.imshow('threshold', threshold) the image is fine but the array is printed in zeros, which is what's making me confused. With np.where(), I wanted to make sure my elements are either 0 or 1, I left it there to see if it's useful but nothing changed whatsoever.